# Common Table Expression Where Roots are not present in both columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

This is a variation of the normal CTE where you find all parents of a node. Only difference is:

- The greatest descendant does not have a `null` child. Instead, it's simply not present in the `child` column.

Here is my attempt:

```
insert into t (parent, child) values (1, 2)
insert into t (parent, child) values (1, 3)
insert into t (parent, child) values (4, 2)
insert into t (parent, child) values (2, 5)
insert into t (parent, child) values (2, 6)
insert into t (parent, child) values (9, 6)
insert into t (parent, child) values (6, 7)
insert into t (parent, child) values (6, 8)

with cte as
( 
    select child, parent, 0 as level 
    from t
    where parent = 5
    union all
    select q.child, q.parent, level+1 
    from t q
    inner join cte as c on c.parent= q.child
)

select distinct parent from cte 
where parent <> 5
```

In this case, when I try to get all parents for `5`, nothing is found because `5` isn't a parent to anyone. If I try to find all parents for `2`, it succeeds however because `2` is a parent to `5` and `6`.

Comment: This is not a viable hierarchy.  2 & 6 are listed twice as a children.  I even switched the field name thinking maybe is was copy/paste error.  Your cte will buld a hierarchy, you just may not like the results   6 had the largest population

Comment: I never said it was a tree. Nothing says a child can't have multiple parents or a parent can't have multiple children.

Comment: If this is a free-for/ad-hoc hierachy, that's fine.  I agree a child can have multiple parents (i.e. a report can belong to Risk Analytics and Quarterly Results),  But then why the question?  Clearly 5 is not a parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `5` is not a parent to anyone, then your filter `parent=5` will never give any output. `5` is a `child` and you want to find all parent above it:

```
declare @t table (parent int, child int)

insert into @t (parent, child)
values (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (4, 2),
 (2, 5),
 (2, 6),
 (9, 6),
 (6, 7),
 (6, 8)

;with cte as
( 
    select child, parent, 0 as level 
    from @t
    where child = 5 ---<<<
    union all
    select q.child, q.parent, level+1 
    from @t q
    inner join cte as c on c.parent= q.child
)

select distinct parent from cte 
where parent <> 5
```

[image]

Comment: Ah. Thanks. That was really dumb of me. Changed `parent` to `child` and it worked.